# Purchases always successful even when I delete postback script

Tags: postback, android-pay, google-code

I'm using *Google Wallet for Digital Goods* (in *Sandbox Mode*) and it worked fine for month or two, and information on the database was updated accordingly. Recently, however, the purchases were completing, however the database was not updated.

For debugging, I deleted the *postback* script from the server, but very strangely, Google keeps completing the purchases even though the postback script no longer exists!!

So now every purchase goes through no matter what!

*Google* claims it was successful within the iframe (which pops up on the client to initiate and complete a purchase).

I'm using the sandbox credit card.

Is there a bug in Google's code?

Comment: What happens when you mock a Google postback to the url defined in your sandbox account?

Comment: Well, is that even necessary? If I make sure the postback is nowhere on the server, it must not be about if the processing of the data is done correctly, rather why is it successful if no file exists? I could try...

Comment: Yup - just can't repro - I can simply not respond _properly_ and it bombs out for me as expected. Hence, the question...

Comment: What do you mean by "can't reproduce", "can't respond properly" and "bombs out"? You mean that you have the same problem, or that you can't reproduce it?

Comment: The latter. I cannot reproduce the issue. If I purposely set my postback handler to not respond properly - e.g. something like not returning the Google `orderId` the transaction fails as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Somehow, the `postback url` field inside the [sandbox settings page](https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/settings.html) was deleted.

I had set it correctly some time ago but for some *unknown* reason it was missing.

It seems from this that `Google` completes purchases when no postback is specified.

-- dragonfire